# the h2 interpolation does not get updated when the variable changes

Tags: angular, typescript

the h2 interpolation does not get updated when the variable changes
what I'm trying to do is to add letters to displayedWord variable To appear as if the word gets typed
TS

```
  displayedWord = ''
  words = ['Innovation', 'Inspiration']


  changeWord = (words) => {

    const wordArray = this.words[0].split('')
    const lettersToDisplay = []

    for (let i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        const letter = wordArray[i];
        lettersToDisplay.push(letter)
        this.displayedWord = lettersToDisplay.join('');
        console.log(this.displayedWord);
      }, 1000 * i);
    }
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changeWord(this.words);
  }
```

HTML

```
        <h2 class="about__title">We help you discover the power of {{displayedWord}}_
```

Comment: is your component or any of its parents marked as `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to change :

```
setTimeout(function() { ... } )
```

To:

```
setTimeout(() => {...})
```

In order `this` to be referencing the component instance.

Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

States that:

> Does not have its own bindings to `this`.

compared to *function expression*

Comment: Oh okay, did not notice
thank you